# Lubuntu installation - - AMD athlon -- boot bypassing grub screen

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu 14.04 for a friend, on an old xp machine, a Packard-Bell AMD Athlon 64.

The installation, apparently went smoothly, however when I rebooted, Lubuntu booted straight to the Lubuntu splash screen, that is, by passing the expected grub screen.

Just wondering has anyone seen this type of behaviour before?

I am unsure if it is a bad install or just an artifact of the older hardware?

Comment: This is the default behavior, when Lubuntu is the only OS. It's neither a bad install, nor an artifact. What exactly do you want to do with the Grub menu?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Mike. That has answered my question.

Comment: if you could put that in the answer box @mikewhatever that would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior, when Lubuntu is the only OS installed. 
It's neither a bad install, nor an artifact, and you can still get to the Grub menu by holding the `Shift` key at boot.